# How to change values in specific rows depending on given condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to do something like this:

```
for row in df:
if row['Country'] == 'unknown':
    row['Country'] = city2country_mapping[row['city']]
```

Country and City are columns.

'city2country_mapping' is a dictionary where key:value pair is 'city':'country'.

(basically i'm trying to fill in the unknowns by getting country from dictionary as i know city for each row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize this with [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['country'] = df.country.where(
    df.country != 'unknown', df.city.map(city2country_mapping))
```

`df.city.map(city2country_mapping)` will first create a Series that contains the corresponding country for each city, and then use this to replace the `unknown` countries in the `country` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `apply`:

```
df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: city2country_mapping[row['city']] 
                                     if row['Country'] == 'unknown' else row['Country'], axis=1)
```

Lambda returns city from mapping in case of 'unknown' country and otherwise just a country in this row.

Comment: I tried this but what it seems to do is convert my df into a series of countries. All other data is lost.

Comment: @AakashDusane fixed, try now :)

Comment: Works now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Editing specific rows: `DataFrame.loc` vs. `Series.where`**

The standard option for editing specific rows (a "slice") of a `DataFrame` object is [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

The accepted answer uses a neat application of [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) to rewrite the `df.Country` Series, which is more succinct for this specific task.

**Recoding values: `.apply` vs. `.map`**

You can use `.map()` to recode a Series directly with a dictionary - no need to `.apply()` a lambda function.

**Example**

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['unknown', 'USA', 'unknown', 'UK', 'USA', 'unknown'],
                   'City': ['London', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'New York', 'Paris']
                  })
city2country_mapping = {'London': 'UK', 'New York': 'USA', 'Paris': 'France'}

# print(df)

#    Country      City
# 0  unknown    London
# 1      USA  New York
# 2  unknown  New York
# 3       UK    London
# 4      USA  New York
# 5  unknown     Paris

df.loc[df.Country == 'unknown', 'Country'] = df[df.Country == 'unknown'].City.map(city2country_mapping)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Country      City
0      UK    London
1     USA  New York
2     USA  New York
3      UK    London
4     USA  New York
5  France     Paris
```

Comment: Really simple solution. Thanks!